# PHP best way to call method by string with arguments?

Tags: php, web-services

I am creating a very simple web service and I don't want to bother with some framework to implement it.

I am trying to make it so I can call a method on a class by using a string like

```
$myMethod = "test";
$args = array("arg1", "arg2");
$myMethod();
```

The problem is there may be a different number of arguments for each method. Aside from passing in just an array of arguments is there a way to call $myMethod() and pass in the arguments like you would normally myMethod(arg1, arg2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is with `call_user_func_array()`, but this function is **very slow**.

You know what they told you about not using `eval()` in PHP? Think of `call_user_*` functions just like `eval()` - they're horribly slow.

**Solutions**

**1)** You can pass arguments blindly like this:

```
$mtd = 'test';
$args = array('a','b');
array_pad($args, 8, null);
return $mtd($args[0],$args[1],$args[2],$args[3],$args[4],$args[5],$args[6],$args[7]);
```

**2)** You can count the arguments and call a different hard-coded function for each:

```
$mtd = 'test';
$args = array('a','b');

switch(count($args)){
    case 0: return $mtd();
    case 1: return $mtd($args[0]);
    case 2: return $mtd($args[0],$args[1]);
    case 3: return $mtd($args[0],$args[1],$args[2]);
    case 4: return $mtd($args[0],$args[1],$args[2],$args[3]);
    case 5: return $mtd($args[0],$args[1],$args[2],$args[3],$args[4]);
    default: return call_user_func_array($mtd, $args); // slow, but safe
}
```

**3)** Finally, you can do the same thing Drupal did to solve this; generate and cache PHP code. The generated code is hard-coded to work on a specific number of arguments, but clearing the cache will make it increase/decrease argument count as necessary. Plus, it's the fast way possible.

Comment: Thanks, I will take that into consideration when I need to decide about call_user_* stuff

Answer (score 6):

use call_user_func_array : http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Answer (score 1):

Also, just to help you wield variable number of parameters, see `func_get_args()`

```
function mysomething() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    print_r( $args );
}
```

You can thus move variable number of arguments from function to function.

Comment: Too bad there isn't a way to call the same function `func_get_args(myFunctionIdentifier);` and pass in the function name so you can know of its argument list when you want to call it. Guess that would break with PHP's method of overloading

Comment: @Walt You can, PHP has Reflection support; use the `ReflectionFunction` class.